# woocoomerce replace classes in checkout page and My account page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to replace billing country class from "form-row-wide" to "form-row-first" in both checkout and in My account page but it's not working.

here is the code I am using

```
/*replace country class form-row-wide to form-row-first*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'country_class_change', 9999 );

function country_class_change( $fields ) {

$fields['billing']['billing_country']['class'][0] = 'my-field-class form-row-first';

return $fields;
}
```

I used earlier the filter "woocommerce_checkout_fields" but that only worked in the checkout not in My Account page. How to do for both. whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with below code

```
// change country class
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'country_class_change' );

function country_class_change( $address_fields ) {

    // change country class
    $address_fields['country']['class'] = array('my-field-class form-row-first');

    return $address_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the Woocommerce template structure files. The form-row-wide class appears in a number of Woocommerce files. Simply change the markup to add any classes in your Woocommerce custom theme i.e

woocommerce/auth/form-login.php 
woocommerce/cart/shipping-calculator.php 
woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php 
woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-account.php 
woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php

Comment: Doing this method then I have to manually change each folder each time woocoomerce update. I want the  code to be in function child theme.

Comment: Not really. This is why woocommerce allows child themes. If you alter code in the plugins folder then yes, it'll be overwritten by an update. If you copy the template files into your theme then you can customise woocommerce anyway you like. Not every woocommerce site looks the same, this is how you achieve it. - https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/theming/

Comment: ok thx for that. i'll try to do it and post update.